# In Pandas how I check if specifics columns give true in the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dflike that

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | False |
| 2 | False | True | False |
| 3 | False | False | True |
| 4 | True | False | True |
| 5 | False | True | True |
| 6 | False | False | False |
| 7 | False | True | False |

I want to check my df to know if there are rows with more than a True value because I expect that every rows has not more than one column with True value. All False is fine, 1 True is fine, if there were two o more True in the same row would be a problem.
Every row is a specific event. I think that columns shouldn't overlap but I'm not sure so I have to check because in the future I'll need to count the "True" and if a row had more than a true the same event would be counted twice.

So I expect to have this output

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | True | False | True |
| 5 | False | True | True |

Comment: You can perform arithmetic ops on boolean as if they're float: `df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].mean().ge(0.5)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, boolean values can actually be treated as integers and have operations done to them. Simply, `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

Since we know this fact, you can take the `sum` of each row of data and check to see if it is `>1`. If that is the case, then you know that there are more than 1 True values.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load your DF Here...

#Get the sum of the columns you want to check and create a mask where that sum is more than 1.
new_df = df[df[['Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D']].sum(axis=1) > 1]

print(new_df)
```

With this method, it is important to make sure that you only use columns that have `boolean` values though. Don't accidentally include numerical columns (like `Column A`) in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the unwanted column(s), [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) the boolean columns to count the `True`, and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to select the rows with more than one ([`gt(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)):

```
out = df[df.drop(columns=['Column A']).sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
```

Or, selecting all boolean columns automatically with [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
out = df[df.select_dtypes(bool).sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
```

Output:

```
   Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
3         4      True     False      True
4         5     False      True      True
```